# pandas: concat data frame with different column name

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this data frame

```
id   x   y
0    a   hello
0    b   test
1    c   hi
2    a   hi
3    d   bar
```

I want to concat x and y into a single column like this keeping their ids

```
id   x
0    a
0    b
1    c
2    a
3    d
0    hello
0    test
1    hi
2    hi
3    bar
```

And how if I want to give a new name for the concat column? (e.g. 'x' to 'xy')

Comment: I don't want my id set as index. It should still be a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `pandas.concat` includes the option to set new `column` names [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), but you could assign like so:

Starting from:

```
   id  x      y
0   0  a  hello
1   0  b   test
2   1  c     hi
3   2  a     hi
4   3  d    bar

df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df.x, df.y]), columns=['xy']).reset_index()

   id     xy
0   0      a
1   0      b
2   1      c
3   2      a
4   3      d
5   0  hello
6   0   test
7   1     hi
8   2     hi
9   3    bar
```

Comment: I don't want my id set as index. It should still be a column

Comment: This produces wrong result. The id column in the result is an index, not id. So it produces {'id':[0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]}

Comment: Updated to hopefully make the steps more transparent - I did in fact set `id` as `index` before `concat`.

Comment: Yes. I was planning to use set_index as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If ordering of rows is not important, you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print df
   id  x      y
0   0  a  hello
1   0  b   test
2   1  c     hi
3   2  a     hi
4   3  d    bar

s = df.set_index('id').stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'xy'

print pd.DataFrame(s).reset_index()
   id     xy
0   0      a
1   0  hello
2   0      b
3   0   test
4   1      c
5   1     hi
6   2      a
7   2     hi
8   3      d
9   3    bar
```

Comment: I don't want my id set as index. It should still be a column

Comment: Then you can reset index. No problem. Or is it problem?

Comment: Yes. This works as well. But I think Stefan's answer is much simpler.