# Concat list of pandas data frame, but ignoring column name

Tags: python, pandas, rbind

Sub-title: Dumb it down pandas, stop trying to be clever.

I've a list (`res`) of single-column pandas data frames, each containing the same kind of numeric data, but each with a different column name. The row indices have no meaning. I want to put them into a single, very long, single-column data frame.

When I do `pd.concat(res)` I get one column per input file (and loads and loads of NaN cells). I've tried various values for the parameters (*), but none that do what I'm after.

Edit: Sample data:

```
res = [
    pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'C':[100,200,300,400]}),
]
```

I have an ugly-hack solution: copy every data frame and giving it a new column name:

```
newList = []
for r in res:
  r.columns = ["same"]
  newList.append(r)
pd.concat( newList, ignore_index=True )
```

Surely that is not the best way to do it??

BTW, [pandas: concat data frame with different column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282847/841830) is similar, but my question is even simpler, as I don't want the index maintained. (I also start with a list of N single-column data frames, not a single N-column data frame.)

*: E.g. `axis=0` is default behaviour. `axis=1` gives an error. `join="inner"` is just silly (I only get the index). `ignore_index=True` renumbers the index, but I stil gets lots of columns, lots of NaNs.

---

**UPDATE for empty lists**

I was having problems (with all the given solutions) when the data had an empty list, something like:

```
res = [
    pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'C':[]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'D':[100,200,300,400]}),
]
```

The trick was to force the type, by adding `.astype('float64')`. E.g.

```
pd.Series(np.concatenate([df.values.ravel().astype('float64') for df in res]))
```

or:

```
pd.concat(res,axis=0).astype('float64').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use list comphrension such has:

```
import pandas as pd
res = [
    pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'C':[100,200,300,400]}),
]


x = []
[x.extend(df.values.tolist()) for df in res]
pd.DataFrame(x)

Out[49]: 
      0
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     9
4     8
5     7
6     6
7     5
8     4
9   100
10  200
11  300
12  400
```

I tested speed for you.

```
%timeit x = []; [x.extend(df.values.tolist()) for df in res]; pd.DataFrame(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop
%timeit pd.Series(pd.concat(res, axis=1).values.ravel()).dropna()
1000 loops, best of 3: 920 µs per loop
%timeit pd.concat(res, axis=1).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 902 µs per loop
%timeit pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(res, axis=1).values.ravel(), columns=['col']).dropna()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
%timeit pd.Series(np.concatenate([df.values.ravel() for df in res]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.2 µs per loop
```

looks like

```
pd.Series(np.concatenate([df.values.ravel() for df in res]))
```

is the fastest.

Comment: Could be `pd.concat([x.rename(columns=lambda c: 'same') for x in res], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the timings; it wasn't time sensitive in this case, but good to know the quickest idiom in case I ever need it for a large amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (pd.concat(res, axis=1))
     A  B      C
0  1.0  9  100.0
1  2.0  8  200.0
2  3.0  7  300.0
3  NaN  6  400.0
4  NaN  5    NaN
5  NaN  4    NaN

print (pd.concat(res, axis=1).stack().reset_index(drop=True))
0       1.0
1       9.0
2     100.0
3       2.0
4       8.0
5     200.0
6       3.0
7       7.0
8     300.0
9       6.0
10    400.0
11      5.0
12      4.0
dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for flattening:

```
print (pd.Series(pd.concat(res, axis=1).values.ravel()).dropna())
0       1.0
1       9.0
2     100.0
3       2.0
4       8.0
5     200.0
6       3.0
7       7.0
8     300.0
10      6.0
11    400.0
13      5.0
16      4.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(res, axis=1).values.ravel(), columns=['col']).dropna())
      col
0     1.0
1     9.0
2   100.0
3     2.0
4     8.0
5   200.0
6     3.0
7     7.0
8   300.0
10    6.0
11  400.0
13    5.0
16    4.0
```

Solution with `list comprehension`:

```
print (pd.Series(np.concatenate([df.values.ravel() for df in res])))
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       9
4       8
5       7
6       6
7       5
8       4
9     100
10    200
11    300
12    400
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Along those lines, but I have a list of 1-column data frames, not the 6-column data frame in your example.

Comment: I just added sample data to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my sample data (the frames have differing number of rows), as my  `pd.concat(res)` output wasn't as nice as yours. But your first answer does work for that too. (The ravel solution does not - the NaNs survive; I could append `.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)` but...)